# CardLayout in Swing Doesnt work with Box Layout?

Tags: java, swing, cardlayout, boxlayout, box

I have some Swing code that uses a card layout for multiple panels. When I try to position buttons on my Home Panel, it doesnt work, like when I try and make the home header aligned. Is there anyway to make this work with the Box layout?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main extends JFrame {
JFrame frame;

JPanel content;
JPanel Home;
JPanel Select;
JPanel Create;

CardLayout cardLayout;

JButton select;
JButton create;
JButton homebutton;
JButton homebutton2;
JTextField headerHome;
JTextField headerCreate;
JTextField headerSelect;
private JTextPane dfgdsfgdfgdfgTextPane;
private JPanel panel1;


public Main() {
    frame = new JFrame("Ice Cream Maker");
    content = new JPanel();
    Home = new JPanel();
    Select = new JPanel();
    Create = new JPanel();
    cardLayout = new CardLayout();

    homebutton = new JButton("Home");
    homebutton.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(50, 80));
    homebutton.setVisible(true);
    homebutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            cardLayout.show(content, "Home");
        }
    });


    homebutton2 = new JButton("Home");
    homebutton2.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(50, 80));
    homebutton2.setVisible(true);
    homebutton2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            cardLayout.show(content, "Home");
        }
    });

    Create.add(homebutton);
    Select.add(homebutton2);


    select = new JButton("Select");
    select.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(50, 80));
    select.setVisible(true);
    select.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            cardLayout.show(content, "Select");
        }
    });
    Home.add(select, Box.createHorizontalStrut(100));

    create = new JButton("Create");
    create.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(50, 80));
    create.setVisible(true);
    create.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            cardLayout.show(content, "Create");
        }
    });
    Home.add(create);

    headerHome = new JTextField("Ice Cream Maker!");
    headerHome.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(100, 200));
    headerHome.setVisible(true);
    Home.add(headerHome, Box.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

    headerCreate = new JTextField("Create an Ice Cream!");
    headerCreate.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(100, 200));
    headerCreate.setVisible(true);
    Create.add(headerCreate);

    headerSelect = new JTextField("Select an Ice Cream");
    headerSelect.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(100, 200));
    headerSelect.setVisible(true);
    Select.add(headerSelect);


    content.setLayout(cardLayout);
    content.add(Home, "Home");
    content.add(Select, "Select");
    content.add(Create, "Create");
    cardLayout.show(content, "Home");
    frame.add(content);
    frame.setSize(640, 480);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);


}


public static void main(String[] args) {

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new Main();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? And where do you use BoxLayout in your code above? I'm confused as you don't show us what isn't working in your attempt.

Comment: Note I see you trying to use Box constants, but in containers that have not been given a BoxLayout. A container has to be given a BoxLayout for it to work like a BoxLayout-using container. Makes sense, no?

Comment: Okay, then how can I position it like Center and stuff like that in a CardLayout?

Comment: You must give the JPanel that is being added to the CardLayout-using container a layout manager of its own. BoxLayout won't magically work on this JPanel unless you set the layout with BoxLayout yourself.